# How to sum all the current product prices of a user cart together as total price

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on an Online Store project using PHP and MySQLi. Most of this project is done and now I'm struggling with total price that a user must pay. This total price is showing in the `cart.php` page (where users can see all the product items that they have added earlier). So it must be set to the total price of all current items.

So here is the code of `cart.php`:

```
if(isset($_GET['cart_id']))
{
    $cart_id = $_GET['cart_id'];
    $get_add = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cart_id = '$cart_id'";
    $run_add = mysqli_query($con,$get_add);

    $cart_items = [];
    while ($row_results = mysqli_fetch_array($run_add)){
         $item = array(
             'table_id' => $row_results['table_id'],
             'cart_id' => $row_results['cart_id'],
             'pro_id' => $row_results['product_id'],
             'pro_title' => $row_results['product_title'],
             'pro_price' => $row_results['product_price'],
             'pro_img' => $row_results['product_image'],
             'pro_supplier' => $row_results['product_supplier'],
             'qty' => $row_results['qty'],
             'cart_ip' => $row_results['cart_ip'],
          );
          $cart_items[] = $item;
     }
     foreach ($cart_items as $cart) {
         echo $cart['pro_price']
     }
}
```

The table `cart` structure goes like this:

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl5BR.png)

So now I want to print the sum of all products as `total_price`, till now I tried several different ways but I could not get the result.

So if you know how to solve this question, please let me know.. I really really appreciate that...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need  the sum of qty*product_price you could sum this way

```
$tot = 0;
while ($row_results = mysqli_fetch_array($run_add)){
        $cart_items[] = array(
             'table_id' => $row_results['table_id'],
             'cart_id' => $row_results['cart_id'],
             'pro_id' => $row_results['product_id'],
             'pro_title' => $row_results['product_title'],
             'pro_price' => $row_results['product_price'],
             'pro_img' => $row_results['product_image'],
             'pro_supplier' => $row_results['product_supplier'],
             'qty' => $row_results['qty'],
             'cart_ip' => $row_results['cart_ip'],
          );

        $tot +=  $row_results['qty']*$row_results['product_price'];
     }
     foreach ($cart_items as $cart) {
         echo $cart['pro_price'];
     }
     echo $tot;
```